# “Who came in like a white kittling."

Tags: meaning, etymology

Within the context of 17th century *witch-hunting*, a **[kittling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kittle)** was apparently commonly known as some kind of animal.

Perhaps the obvious first guess is a misspelled *kitten*, or some kind of *bird*, or a white *calf* – or *lamb*?

What animal was “Holt” the witch's familiar spirit?

Reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyewacket_%28familiar_spirit%29
- http://preview.tinyurl.com/zyp8kp4 (Preview to a Google Books link: The Esoteric Codex: Witch Hunting, By Samuel Covington)

Comment: "Cat" would be a fair guess, since the Old French for cat is "chitoun", and "kittling" comes close phonetically.  Observe that most of the other beings mentioned are small animals.

Comment: Oh jeez.  I misread the Wikipedia entry.  I thought it said the first listed entry was NOT a cat, so I couldn't figure out what it was.

Comment: Joseph Wright in his *English Dialect Dictionary* (vol III, H-L, Oxford,1905) lists the noun KITLING "a kitten, a small cat" and relates it to the verb KITTLE, "to bring forth young, used gen.  of cats but also of other small animals...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a Scottish  term for ***kitten***:

> - (Scot.) Kitten, also tickling.

([Folk-Etymology](https://books.google.it/books?id=fXrlvr_kPXwC&pg=PA468&lpg=PA468&dq=a%20white%20kittling%20meaning&source=bl&ots=uwhQm7Z91S&sig=nBXYYagz4dL6VpbYSB8XvmDzUag&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR9ejLuPrJAhXFRg8KHf5cANEQ6AEIITAD#v=onepage&q=kittling&f=false))